# Nginx/Proxy Help Subdomain to Specific Port

Tags: nginx, proxy

So I've currently got a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B setup with a webserver which is hosted on the default ports. It has a bunch of small websites on it with their own domains.

However, I've also got another Pi in which I'm hosting a Teamspeak server, I'm wanting to have a sub domain to point to my Teamspeak server only, using a different domain name. But I want the sub domain to only point to the Teamspeak and not the default site for Nginx.

I've read that I can do this via a SVR record, however I've read it's not the best way and it's better to use a reverse proxy or something of the sort. Also the SVR record doesn't seem to be working for me.

I'm looking how I would do this along with somewhere I can learn more about this kind of thing etc. If I am needed to be pointed elsewhere please let me know. :)

Thanks in advance,

~Blood

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had the Teamspeak 3 service wrong for the SVR record. Everywhere I looked it said to use `_teamspeak` for the service, but you're supposed to use `_ts3` instead.